# metrics for evaluating the performance of a load balancing algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I have proposed a load balancing algorithm for distributed systems which monitors the load on each device in this system and moves excess load from over-loaded device to less-loaded device. What are best metrics for evaluating the result before and after load balancing?

I studied several papers and found metrics like "average response time" and "average waiting time" for tasks. What are some other metrics that I can use to evaluate the result of my load balancing algorithm?

Comment: Have you measured "average response time" and "average waiting time"? Why do you want to seek other metrics? Some other metrics are "average turnaround time", "throughput (during peak time or a day)", "CPU utilization", "load average", "number of cancelled requests". Please clarify _in the question_.

Comment: Who or what motivates you to propose the load balancing algorithm? The metrics should answer those motivations. What changes can be observed in the system once the algorithm is put into action? Those changes could be included in the metric.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is suitable here.  The "best metrics" sounds like a matter of opinion to me.  "What are some other metrics" sounds too open-ended to be a good fit here.  How do you plan to evaluate answers?  How are we supposed to evaluate answers?  Any community votes?